# How to get the email is in which field, when used FIND_IN_SET?

Tags: mysql

I am using FIND_IN_SET in mysql query 
this query will give output that email id is in from_email or to_email.
this query runs fine. 
but the question is I am not able to detect that it finally found in to_email or in from_email. I want that it gives me finally only the field which this email is carried.
Following is my email id

```
SELECT mail_id, from_firstname, from_lastname, from_email, to_firstname, to_lastname, to_email
FROM support_mail sm WHERE
( 

( FIND_IN_SET ('".$email_id."', sm.to_email) ) AND ( (sm.to_firstname <> '') AND (sm.to_firstname <> 'None') )

OR 

( FIND_IN_SET ('".$email_id."', sm.from_email) ) AND ( (sm.from_firstname <> '') AND (sm.from_firstname <> 'None') )

)
```

Comment: I actually want the first name and last name of that email. 
(all (from+to) email , firstname, lastname are in CSV format in field

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below, it might solve your problem:

```
SELECT mail_id, from_firstname, from_lastname, from_email, to_firstname, to_lastname, to_email
(IF( FIND_IN_SET ('".$email_id."', sm.to_email) ) AND ( (sm.to_firstname <> '') AND (sm.to_firstname <> 'None') ),"yes","no") AS MailTo,
(IF(FIND_IN_SET ('".$email_id."', sm.from_email) ) AND ( (sm.from_firstname <> '') AND (sm.from_firstname <> 'None')),"yes","no") AS MailFrom
FROM support_mail sm WHERE
( 
OR 

( FIND_IN_SET ('".$email_id."', sm.to_email) ) AND ( (sm.to_firstname <> '') AND (sm.to_firstname <> 'None') )

OR 

( FIND_IN_SET ('".$email_id."', sm.from_email) ) AND ( (sm.from_firstname <> '') AND (sm.from_firstname <> 'None') )
)
```

Comment: It is giving error .

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND 
  ( 
    (sm.to_firstname <> '') AND (sm.to_firstname <> 'None') 
  ),'ye' at line 5